# Unsure if mysql_fetch_array is returning results

Tags: mysql

so I'm trying to fetch data from MySQL but I'm not sure if the array get returned.

This is a test php file to check if the function is working.

```
<?php
include_once('Private/dbInfo.php');
 $db = new dbObject();
 $db->connect();
 $db->getBusInfo();
?>
```

here is the function. Also the database named markers has the fields name, id, and time but for testing purposes just trying to get the name. Why is the while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))  not getting entered?

```
public function getBusInfo() {
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `markers`")
        or die(mysql_error()); 

        while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
        { 
          echo "name"+$info['name'];
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the following reasons why your while statement is not getting entered:

1. There is some error occurring before it gets to the while statement and you have display errors turned off
2. The getBusInfo() function is never being called, meaning the code is calling some different getBusInfo() function somewhere
3. Your table is empty (no data)